# at89c51 power supply

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, current, integrated-circuit

I am making a project using at89c51. I used my mobile charger (output: 5V, 1A)
 as the power supply. Will my IC get damaged due to the high current?

I asked cause, without loading the program I connected the pin40(Vcc) and pin20(gnd) just to check whether all the port pins except port0 give output 1 or not, which is as I believe by default. And I got haphazard values which changed everytime I turned the supply off and on.

I also couldn't find the supply current range in the datasheet so got more confused.

Please advise.

Comment: Nope, my problem is that by default the pins of port 1,2,3 are logic 1 when no program is loaded, which i didnt get, so i asked whether the supply is at fault.

Comment: If your charger gives 5V (check this), it should work. It will not always give 1A, that's just the maximum current that the charger can handle. The actual current is determined by the device you connect to it. That's explained in the link @PeterJ gave you.

Comment: Do you have EA at VCC?

Comment: @venny, no i have not connected EA at Vcc. Is there any significane?

Comment: @Deep Yes, when EA is low, GPIO ports are used as external memory interface.

Comment: @venny, ok so if i connect EA to vcc then pins of all ports 1,2,3 will be 1 by default if no program is loaded?

Comment: @Deep That is what I would expect. Maybe it will require functioning oscillator as well, if there is no internal one.

Comment: @venny, i will try and revert back to you.

Comment: @venny, connected both the clock circuit as well as EA to Vcc. Problem still persists.